# Logs not working on new Magento install

Tags: magento-1.9, error, oauth

I have just installed Magento 1.9 on Nginx and Ubuntu.

Everything seems to be working ok however when trying to access /oauth/initiate I am getting an HTTP 401.

I want to view the logs so I can find out more about this issue.

I have enabled the logs in **system > configuration > developer** however when I checked my **webroot/magento/var** I had no logs folder.

I created a logs file and put the files `system.log` and `exception.log` and chown'd to **www-data:www-data** and gave them *777 file permissions*.

Magento is still not updating these log files.

Can anybody help me find out why I am getting an HTTP 401 when I try and access **/oauth/initiate** please?

Comment: you will also have to give 777 permission to /var/log folder.

Comment: Have you cleared the configuration cache after turning on logs?